# How to change font style like color, size and alignment of text in google-app-scripts (GMAIL)?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-in

I am trying to change the font style in google app script for a card service in gmail add-in.

Sample code -

`CardService.newCardBuilder()
.addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("Sample Text"))`

In the above code **'color'** is working fine but not the **'size'** attribute and also I am trying to align it to right.

Is there any way to make things happen? Or any better approach for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [TextParagraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-paragraph) that `CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("Sample Text")` returns another `TextParagraph` for chaining.

TextParagraph supports [basic HTML formatting](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting).

When setting the text content of these widgets, just include the corresponding HTML tags.

### For example:

> `CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<font color="#ea9999">test</font>')`

Comment: The color attribute is working fine but I want to set the font size too. Is there any function for that?

Comment: No, you may not change size, it isn't among the supported formatting. Please consider accepting the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Actually there are some apps which is doing the same. For example - "keep notes" in Gmail (by google) which looks great in UI/UX. If they can do it then why we can't?

Comment: You can find an open request to add this feature to Slides in Google's Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/161477080 . Add a star next to the issue number to reflect you want this feature too.